# Pagination button dynamically collapse if more than 10 pages , Bootstrap pagination

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, paginator

Im trying to build a custom pagination control for div elements in a parent DIV say div_photos. So under parent div Ive more than 500 child divs (Which are actually thumbnails) like this.

```
<div id='div_photos'>
<div class='tile'><img src='myurl'></div>
<div class='tile'><img src='myurl'></div>
<div class='tile'><img src='myurl'></div>
.........
<div class='tile'><img src='myurl'></div>
</div>
```

So I did the pagination control below like this

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
     <h3 class=" page-info" style="margin-top:14px;"></h3>
     </div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
      <div class="pagination pagination-large pull-right">
            <ul class="pager"></ul>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery for the creation of paginator

```
var bindPaginator = function () {
    var listElement = $('#div_photos');

    var numItems = listElement.children().size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems / perPage);

    $('.pager').data("curr", 0);
    $('.pager').html('');
    var curr = 0;
    while (numPages > curr) {
        $('<li><a href="javascript:;" class="page_link">' + (curr + 1) + '</a></li>').appendTo('.pager');
        curr++;
    }

    $('.pager .page_link:first').addClass('active');

    listElement.children().css('display', 'none');
    listElement.children().slice(0, perPage).css('display', 'block');

    $('.pager li a').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).parents('li:first').index();
        $('.pager:first li').eq(index).find('a').css({ 'background-color': '#337ab7', 'color': 'white', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        $('.pager:first li').not(':eq(' + index.toString() + ')').find('a').css({ 'background-color': 'white', 'color': '#337ab7', 'font-weight': 'normal' });
        $('.pager:last li').eq(index).find('a').css({ 'background-color': '#337ab7', 'color': 'white', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        $('.pager:last li').not(':eq(' + index.toString() + ')').find('a').css({ 'background-color': 'white', 'color': '#337ab7', 'font-weight': 'normal' });
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf() - 1;
        goTo(clickedPage, perPage);
    });
    showPagerInfo(0);
};
function previous() {
    var goToPage = parseInt($('.pager').data("curr")) - 1;
    if ($('.active').prev('.page_link').length == true) {
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
}

function next() {
    goToPage = parseInt($('.pager').data("curr")) + 1;
    if ($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length == true) {
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
}

function goTo(page) {

    var startAt = page * perPage,
      endOn = startAt + perPage;
    var listElement = $('#div_photos');
    listElement.children().css('display', 'none').slice(startAt, endOn).css('display', 'block');
    $('.pager').attr("curr", page);
    showPagerInfo(page);

}
function showPagerInfo(page)
{
 .....
}
```

Now its showing 28 divs per page using a global variable **perpage**. But when there are lots of thumnails the number of pages will be lot and it looks akward. Instead of that how can we show the paginator dynamically as JQUERY datatable automatically adjusts based on total pages. Something like page numbers after 10 gets shown as just ... and final few numbers to show and when it reaches 10 or 9 the hidden numbers to show

Here is how the current setup looks like
[image]